# MySQL to JSON - Combining Two Queries / Formatting

Tags: php, json

I am using PHP/MySQL to run a query and encode it as JSON, but I'm unsure how to get the JSON into the form that I need.

Here is my PHP:

```
$myquery1 = "select 'links' as type, source, target, value from table";

$myquery2 = "select 'nodes' as type, name from table2";

$query = mysql_query($myquery1);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

//(and again for myquery2)

echo json_encode($data); //not sure how to combine queries here
```

I would like the JSON to be grouped grouped by "type," like this:

```
{
 "links": [{"source":"58","target":"john","value":"95"},
           {"source":"60","target":"mark","value":"80"}],
 "nodes": 
          [{"name":"john"}, {"name":"mark"}, {"name":"rose"}]
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You're using quotes around `'links'` and `'types'` which will throw a syntax error

Comment: @JayBlanchard it doesn't throw a syntax error (for me) it just makes all values 'links'. Use backtick: `\`` instead of singlequote.

Comment: Thank you for both of those comments.  For some reason, the quotes haven't thrown an error, but I will look into what you said.  However, given the structure above, how can I get to the JSON structure that I'm after?

Comment: @Hacyon you are correct, it's a "dummy variable" so that I have something to group on.  Open to suggestions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$data = array(
    "links" => array(),
    "nodes" => array()
);
..
// for each link
$data["links"][] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
..
// for each node
$data["nodes"][] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

I think `mysql_fetch_assoc` adds each column twice, once by it's name and once by it's index so you will want to do some trimming. ie:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$data["links"][] = array(
    "name" => $row["name"],
    .. etc
)
```

Doing `mysql_num_rows($query)` in the for-loop condition might be a problem. The value never changes but PHP has to run the function every loop. Cache the value or use:

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) !== false) { .. }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you, Halcyon!